# How to create customized table

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I need to create this table:

[image: target]

I'm having problems on the second row, this is what I got:

[image: current]

I'm not understanding where I'm wrong

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{outline} \usepackage{pmgraph} \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{5.1cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{0.2cm}|}

\hline
\textbf{Requisito}  &   R1 & \textbf{Tipo Requisito}  &   Funzionale &     \textbf{Casi d'uso} & 1\\
\cline{1-6}
\hline
\textbf{Descrizione} &
 \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{2cm}{L’utente inserisce le  informazioni relative alla propria forma fisica, alle preferenze relative alle letture tematiche e alla privacy}}
\textbf{Descrizione} & bbb  &   bbbb\\
\cline{1-6}


\textbf{Razionale}  &  cc  &  ccc  &   cccc\\
\cline{1-6}

\textbf{Attore innescante}  &  dd   &  ddd  &   dddd\\
\cline{1-6}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a compileable code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please do not post fragments only, but a full document around this, i.e. with `\documentclass{...}`, the relevant packages and `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. On first glance: `\multirow` is wrongly used, but this is untested by me

Comment: Why did you edit my image uploadings away? :-(

Comment: sorry, i was editing with the full code :( @ChristianHupfer

Comment: For `multirow`, you have to (1) add sufficient rows to make space and (2) leave the cells in those rows empty. `2` rows is not enough and you have not left the cells empty, either. Not with a width of only 2cm, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
%\usepackage{outline} \usepackage{pmgraph} \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{4.1cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{0.2cm}|}

\hline
\textbf{Requisito}   &   R1 & \textbf{Tipo Requisito}  &   Funzionale &     \textbf{Casi d'uso} & 1\\
\cline{1-6}
%\hline
\textbf{Descrizione} &
 \multicolumn{5}{|p{10.2cm}|}{L’utente inserisce le  informazioni relative alla propria forma fisica, alle preferenze relative alle letture tematiche e alla privacy}\\
\cline{1-6}
\textbf{Descrizione} & bbb  &   bbbb                   &              &                         & \\
\cline{1-6}
\textbf{Razionale}   &  cc  &  ccc                     &   cccc       &                         & \\
\cline{1-6}
\textbf{Attore innescante} & &  dd                     &  ddd         &   dddd                  & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If you want to have one cell over 5 columns you have to use `\multicolumn{5}{...}`.  Your columns are too wide. I reduced some sizes to place the table visable on the paper. Please work on this. And at last you missed several `&`, because even if a cell is empty you have to write it. It is easier to see missing `&` if you pretty print your table. See my code please.

At last you should get rid of the vertical lines.  And better use package `booktabs` (`texdoc booktabs` on your terminal for the documentation).

with the result:

[image]

Comment: You need to allow for the separation between columns in figuring the width for the multicolumn else it will get cut off oddly on the right like that.

Comment: Ok it's almost perfect, I've edited it and I need just one more thing, in the last row of the first column I would have the word "innescante" all under attore, how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need somthing like this?

```
\begin{tabular} [t]{|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{3.1cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{0.2cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Requisito}  &   R1 & \textbf{Tipo Requisito}  &   Funzionale &     \textbf{Casi d'uso} & 1\\
\cline{1-6}
\hline
\textbf{Descrizione} & 
\multicolumn{5}{|p{\linewidth}|}{L’utente inserisce le  informazioni relative alla propria forma fisica, alle preferenze relative alle letture tematiche e alla privacy}&\\
\hline
\textbf{Descrizione} & bbb  &   bbbb & bbb & bb &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `5` rather than `4` in the `multicolumn`?

Comment: yes, there must be `\multicolumn{5}{|p{\linewidth}|}`

Comment: I made correction